# Bind dynamically created controls in angularjs

Tags: binding, angularjs

I've got a requirement to add multiple "single-select" select fields

Obviously the first one is added as such:

```
<select class="acctRep" id="acctRep1Select" ng-model="accountUser1" ng-options="user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName for user in accountUsers"></select>
```

To add new ones I've cloned the array that backs the list (accountUsers), and constructed the html text to add to the page:

```
var newElement = '<select class="acctRep" id="acctRep' + nextRepNumber + 'Select" ng-model="accountUser' + nextRepNumber + '" ng-options="user.FirstName+';  .. etc

$('#acctReps').append(newElement);
```

Now I need to let angular know that it needs to populate the items and listen for events.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't add new controls with jquery.  Create an ng-repeat on an array with your data, and when you need to add new selects, just add more data to your array.

Comment: Something like this?: <select class="acctRep" ng-repeat="rep in accountReps" ng-model="rep" ng-options="user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName for user in accountUsers"></select>              It doesn't seem to bind to the accountReps element array.  It won't change according to my selection, but returns to the default.

Comment: I changed my ng-model to accountReps[$index] and bingo.  Thanks for the assist.